# MySql query group by multiple columns and multiple counts together

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am very new to SQL and have never written any complex queries like this one I need help for. I have following table -

```
    Platform   |   TestSuite  |   TestCase   |   Status    |
    -----------|--------------|--------------|-------------|
    Win 2012   |    TS1       |    TC1       |    PASS     |
    Win 2012   |    TS1       |    TC2       |    PASS     |
    Win 2012   |    TS1       |    TC3       |    FAIL     |
    Win 2012   |    TS1       |    TC4       |    ABORT    |
    Win 2012   |    TS2       |    TC5       |    PASS     |
    Win 2012   |    TS2       |    TC6       |    PASS     |
    Win 2012   |    TS2       |    TC7       |    FAIL     |
    Win 2016   |    TS1       |    TC1       |    PASS     |
    Win 2016   |    TS1       |    TC2       |    PASS     |
    Win 2016   |    TS1       |    TC3       |    FAIL     |
    Win 2016   |    TS1       |    TC4       |    ABORT    |
    Win 2016   |    TS2       |    TC5       |    PASS     |
    Win 2016   |    TS2       |    TC6       |    PASS     |
    Win 2016   |    TS2       |    TC7       |    FAIL     |
    -----------|--------------|--------------|-------------|
```

I need to write SQL query to generate following result

```
    Platform   |   TestSuite  |   PASS   |   FAIL  |   ABORT  | TOTAL | 
    -----------|--------------|----------|---------|----------|-------|
    Win 2012   |    TS1       |    2     |    1    |     1    |  4    |
    Win 2012   |    TS2       |    2     |    1    |     0    |  3    |
    Win 2016   |    TS1       |    2     |    1    |     1    |  4    | 
    Win 2016   |    TS2       |    2     |    1    |     0    |  3    |
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `conditional aggregation`.  Here's one approach with `sum` and `case` that should work with most databases (although `mysql` supports short hand versions):

```
select platform, testsuite, 
    sum(case when status = 'pass' then 1 else 0 end) pass,
    sum(case when status = 'fail' then 1 else 0 end) fail,
    sum(case when status = 'abort' then 1 else 0 end) abort,
    count(*) total
from yourtable
group by platform, testsuite
```

---

Or since you are using `mysql`:

```
select platform, testsuite, 
    sum(status = 'pass') pass,
    sum(status = 'fail') fail,
    sum(status = 'abort') abort,
    count(*) total
from yourtable
group by platform, testsuite
```

Comment: This is not working for me. It gives all pass, fail, abort count 0 and total count is also wrong.

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni -- Works fine for me: Here is a simplified fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7TbrnQJaqtXx9S6XgzqTtR/0

Comment: You missed one column 'test case' in this fiddle.

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni That was just a simplified version to demonstrate the usage.  If you want to see it all: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7TbrnQJaqtXx9S6XgzqTtR/1

Comment: This is strange. It works on fiddle however, doesn't work on my terminal. I have selected MySql 5.5 in fiddle. Mine is also MySql 5.5